# Validate email using filter_var PHP

Tags: php, validation, email

I  have a PHP form to get name and email from a user.
For the  email field,  I want to verify that the field is filled out and that the email address is valid.
I am using the code below

Validating if the email field is filled out works, but not the email validation.

```
<tr>
<td align="right">
Email: 
</td><td align="left">
<input type="text" size="25" name="email" value="<? echo $_GET['email']; ? >"/">

<?
#checking if email exists
if ($error_code && !($_GET['email'])) {
echo "<b>Please include your email address.</b>";
}

# validating email
if (!filter_var(($_GET['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true) {
echo "<b>This is not a valid email address.</b>";
}

?>
```

The message "This is not a valid email address" appears even before entering an email address, and it does not show the correct message in case I do enter a wrong email address and submit the form.
What is wrong and why is validating email error shown before submitting the value?

Comment: check form posted before the email check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if (filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) != true) {
     echo "<b>This is not a valid email address.</b>";
}
```

The reason you see the result before you are posting the form is because you are not checking if the `$_GET` array has been set before doing your validation.

So you could do something like..

```
if(isset($_GET['email'])){
    if ($error_code && empty($_GET['email'])) {
        echo "<b>Please include your email address.</b>";
    }

    if (filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) != true) {
        echo "<b>This is not a valid email address.</b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: From the docs, "Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails.". I think this should be "filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false"

Answer (score 0):

Consider to test `isset($_GET['email'])` wrapping all your validation. Also, if this data in coming from a form, check if your method is really GET, otherwise  you want to check parameters with `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and please let me know if this helps

```
<?
#checking if email exists
if ($error_code && !($_GET['email'])) {
echo "<b>Please include your email address.</b>";
}

//# validating email
if (!filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
echo "<b>This is not a valid email address.</b>";
}

?>
```